# Round() function is not returning a value with specified number of digits in python

Tags: python, floating-point, rounding, precision

I am using the round function but it is not returning the number of digits I specified in the parameter of the function.

I used the round function on an entire dataframe like so:
`df.round(6)`

However one of my values is returning more than 6 digits to the right of the decimal point. The initial value is 45014.0160534036 and the returned value is 45014.0160529999.

My guess is there is a floating point error? How can I avoid this? I need to limit the actual value, not the display, so using set_options won't work for me.

Comment: As you guessed this is a limitation of floating points, and you can't go around it other than not using floats. You could use Decimals but not sure if that would integrate well with pandas if you then need to do lots of nifty data processing...?

Comment: Also always good to provide a [mre]

Comment: See [LINK](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#tut-fp-issues) from the official docs explaining such float issues. Note that `round()` gives a **precision** to a number of digits within the limitations explained in the LINK.